# how to get ajax duration from ajaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to extract the duration that an ajax request took from the ajaxError call?

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using beforesend() and complete() is the easiest way to calculate it.

[Getting AJAX Request Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257259/getting-ajax-request-duration)

Comment: If you're just going to link to another question, flag it as a duplicate, don't post a link-only answer.